# Talend: tHiveInput throwing error only when 'Where' clause is used in the Query. Works fine if i remove the clause

Tags: jdbc, hive, hdfs, hadoop2, talend

I am a newbie to both Talend and Hive.
I want to query the Hive table and output the data to csv file.

Created

1. tHiveConnection (I was able to connect to Hive Database)
2. tHiveInput (used the use existing connection and wrote the Query)
3. connected tHiveInput to tMap
4. connected tMap to tfileOutputDelimited
5. tHiveClose

in the point 2) when i write a query `select * from table_name` everything is working fine, I was able to collect the data in csv file
but when i change my query to `select * from table_name where column_name = value` it is failing

Below is the error log

> Exception in component tHiveInput_1 java.sql.SQLException: Error while
>   processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask at
>   org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:277) at
>   org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:376)
>           tHiveInput_1 Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask

Comment: Try to execute your query on hive shell, it looks like a MR error and its not a Talend error !

Comment: `Execution Error, return code 1` usually means **YARN could not launch job** and the root cause can be found in the YARN log. Please look at my comment at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41809178/hive-error-java-lang-throwable-child-error#comment70813666_41809178 because I'm fed up giving always the same basic tips  :-(