# Hive error: java.lang.Throwable: Child Error

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am using CDH 5.9, while executing following hive query it is throwing error. Any idea about the issue?
For normal select query its working but for complex query it results failure.

```
hive> select * from table where dt='22-01-2017' and field like '%xyz%' limit 10;
Query ID = hdfs_20170123200303_44a9c423-4bb3-4f80-ade4-b1312971eb63
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_201701131637_0067, Tracking URL = http://cdhum03.temp-dsc-updates.bms.bz:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201701131637_0067
Kill Command = /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_201701131637_0067
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 6; number of reducers: 0
2017-01-23 20:05:46,563 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%
Ended Job = job_201701131637_0067 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
Job Tracking URL: http://cdhum03.temp-dsc-updates.bms.bz:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201701131637_0067
Examining task ID: task_201701131637_0067_m_000007 (and more) from job job_201701131637_0067
Examining task ID: task_201701131637_0067_r_000000 (and more) from job job_201701131637_0067

Task with the most failures(4):
-----
Task ID:
  task_201701131637_0067_m_000006

URL:
  http://cdhum03.temp-dsc-updates.bms.bz:50030/taskdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201701131637_0067&tipid=task_201701131637_0067_m_000006
-----
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
java.lang.Throwable: Child Error
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:250)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 126.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:237)


FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 6   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does the hive table contains any partitions?

Comment: When Hive reports `Execution Error, return code 2` that simply means **something bad happened inside the YARN job, inspect the YARN logs**. So why don't you just inspect these logs?

Comment: Hint: when Hive reports `Starting Job = job_201701131637_0067` it means that the YARN job ID is actually `application_201701131637_0067` *(the "job" prefix is a legacy thing from before YARN)* and the command line to get the logs is `yarn logs -applicationId application_201701131637_0067 | more ` *(don't forget the "more", because YARN logs are quite verbose)*

Comment: Go to the link and check for detailed error log: http://cdhum03.temp-dsc-updates.bms.bz:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201701131637_0067

Answer (score 0):

Please check your data size as your job needs more space for logs but the jvm are less please scale your cluster or use specific query as you are using -
select * from table where dt='22-01-2017' and field like '%xyz%' limit 10 
, as '%xyz%' will check whole data better to use specific requirement.
Else drop your table and create a new partitioned table with date as a partition column.